# Why does gerrit ls-groups command on my project show no default groups

Tags: github, gerrit

Following the link below, I tried to run ls-groups on my new gerrithub project I set up. I have already put my public ssh key into the my profile settings so I can successfully connect to it. I am the creator of the project, but when I run ls-groups on the project, it connects and runs but returns nothing. I thought each gerrit project had a list of default groups like administrator, etc.?

https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-ls-groups.html

Here is the command example I was using:

```
ssh -p 29418 username@review.gerrithub.io gerrit ls-groups --project username/projectname
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is everything correct. There aren't "default groups" for a recently created project. Only groups with any permission set on this project (or for which a permission is inherited from a parent project) are listed. Administrators group is "privileged" and normally don't need any additional permission set too.